# How would I get just the integer when fetching an integer from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, string, integer

Put simply, I want to be able to output just the number from the list returned without the brackets and commas. Here's what I mean.

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT staffID FROM staff_logins")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    print (x)
```

This is connected to a MySQL database, and outputs this:

```
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(4,)
(5,)
```

This is the primary key for my database, so how would I make it so it outputs just the number without the commas and brackets so I just get the integer and use if statements with the numbers eg.
(doesn't work for me)

```
    if x == 1:
        print ("number 1")
```

currently this doesnt work for me, so is there something I need to do to turn this into a proper integer without the comma. Sorry if this is a silly question but i appreciate any help in advance

Comment: it *always* returns tuples, even if those tuples are of length one... do you know how to use tuples? They are basically just lists you cannot modify

Comment: Just do print (x[0])